# What's the best way to merge two XML Strings with the same tag names?

Tags: java, xml

For example, say I have two XML Strings that I want to merge:

```
<Test>
    <A>false</A>
    <B>true</B>
    <C>Transfers!</C>
</Test>

<Test2>
    <A>false</A>
    <B>false</B>
</Test2>
```

Where the final result looks like (notice, B is now false, because I would like a place to do some sort of logic to determine the final "merged values", in this example, a method would take in two strings, false, and true, and do some AND logic and return "false")

```
<Test>
    <A>false</A>
    <B>false</B>
    <C>Transfers!</C>
</Test>
```

I am thinking of either doing it all by hand, using JAX-B & XPath, or XStream Marshal/Unmarshallers.  Does anyone have an example of the best & most dynamic way to do this?

The element names will change, they will not always be "A" and "B", but the two XML strings I pass in will always have **some** elements in common, but sometimes one XML String/Document may have one or more elements that don't exist in the other document, and in this case those need to be in the final XML result as is.

Comment: You would create the final result the same way you created the two original XML strings (albeit with some processing in-between).

Comment: Assume I am not creating the two original XML Strings, but want to merge them myself with some logic in between :)

Comment: Then you'll first need to re-create the process by which you can read and write those XML strings.  Generally, you'll have an object  that contains the boolean values corresponding to the `A` and `B` elements, and a serialization and deserialization process that converts the object to and from the XML string.  Once you have that, the final solution should be trivial.  Unless, of course, you want to go the whole "parse it by hand, write it back out by hand" route.  But you still need to do some math, so having object representations makes that much easier.

Comment: I know what I need to do "in theory", my question was what's the most dynamic way to do this with possible samplecode :)

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic?"

Comment: The element names will change, they will not always be "A" and "B", but the two XML strings I pass in will always have --some-- elements in common, but sometimes one XML String/Document may have one or more elements that don't exist in the other document, and in this case those need to be in the final XML result as it.  I have updated my original post with this information :)

Comment: That's why you need to do this using first-class code, and not some hokey merger thingy.  Serialization and deserialization is how you should do it in *practice,* not in theory.

Comment: There's a little cognitive dissonance for me when you say doing it "by hand" and follow that with JAX-B and XStream.  If you are doing XML by hand in Java, I would think you mean using DOM, SAX or something at that level.  I think you need to clarify further.  For one, does order matter.  Is the input going to be flat or do you need to support recursing through elements?  Can you have more than one of the same elements in a document?

Comment: Order does not matter.  And the input will be flat, and no recursion through elements necessary. In this case, there will never be duplicate element names within the Test/Test2 blocks.

Comment: I think I know how I am going to approach this --- I will convert the XML strings into two hashtables, and then iterate over one of the hashtables -- and when both hashtables contain the same element, I will do my logic -- and if not, I will just copy the value/key into a third hashtable, and then re-serialize it back into XML.

Answer (score 1):

XML and JaxB will allow you to unmarshall these xml strings/documents into objects.  After that you would feed these two objects as input to a Merge(thing1,thing2) method that then returns the merged object.  You then marshall into an xml string/document and you are complete.

As far as making it "dynamic", that wouldn't be prudent.  You would want to define logic on how each of the potential fields is populated (assuming there will be non-boolean fields).

Note: the marshal/unmarshal gives an opportunity to enforce the schema on the given data.  If you parse the document by hand then you will be forced to validate the xml formatting and validate against a schema, which doesn't sound like a great idea considering that there are libraries out there that every soap web service is already using.

Answer (score 0):

If you have variety of needs of copying/pasting parts of XML messages, in flexible way (specified in configuration), you can use XSL Transformations (Admitted that it may be overkill to introduce XSLT into your project for tiny bit of requirement).

Input XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wrapper>
    <Test>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <country>USA</country>
    </Test>
    <Test1>
            <title>Hide your heart</title>
            <country>UK</country>
    </Test1>
    <Test2>
            <title>Go to Heaven</title>
            <country>Australia</country>
    </Test2>
    <DefaultTest>
        <title>Default Title</title>
        <country>Default Country</country>
    </DefaultTest>
</Wrapper>
```

XSLT document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(),'Test')]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The resultant Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<title>Empire Burlesque</title>
<country>USA</country>

<title>Hide your heart</title>
<country>UK</country>

<title>Go to Heaven</title>
<country>Australia</country>
```